# O cardview perdeu sua "elevação" depois que passei a usá-lo em fragments, como resolver?

Tags: android

Usando em activities a elevação funciona normalmente, depois que coloquei em fragments, ele ficou "plano".

Comment: Não sei se faz muito sentido, mas pode ser um bug do `CardView`. O xml que colocou é o mesmo nos dois?

Comment: sim, é idêntico, não tem nada de diferente, até tentei alterar as propriedades pra ver se resolve mas não resolveu.

Comment: Chegou a tentar a propriedade `cardElevation`? Poderia colocar o XML do `Fragment` e da `Activity` dele como um todo?

Comment: Já usei o cardElevation e não adiantou. Não entendi essa segunda parte

Comment: Você tem que ve como está chamando tipo, android:cardElevation app:cardElevarion cardview:cardElevation

Comment: bom, ainda não adiantou. Não entendi isso que você disse de colocar o XML do Fragment e da Activity como um todo

Comment: Digo que seria bom colocar o XML do layout da Activity e do Fragment, só para ver ser tem algo influenciando.

Answer (score -1):

Parece um problema de margem / preenchimento, tentar definir o atributo cardUseCompatPadding para true. Por exemplo:

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
```

Explicação do doc Android:

> CardView adiciona o preenchimento adicional para desenhar sombras nas plataformas antes L.
>
> Isso pode causar Cards ter diferentes tamanhos entre L e antes L. Se você precisa para alinhar CardView com outros pontos de vista, você pode precisar de recursos dimensão específica versão da API para explicar as mudanças. Como alternativa, você pode definir o sinalizador cardUseCompatPadding como true e CardView irá adicionar os mesmos valores de preenchimento em plataformas L e depois.
>
> Desde a criação da bandeira cardUseCompatPadding a verdade acrescenta lacunas desnecessárias na interface do usuário, o valor padrão é falso.